# ¿Cómo hacen las redes sociales para redireccionar a los usuarios a determinado perfil e imprimir sus datos?

Tags: datos, redes-sociales

Mi duda es la siguiente:

¿Las redes sociales como Facebook, Instagram, Twitter, etc, tienen una pagina para cada usuario?

Es decir, ¿Un código html para cada uno de los usuarios? Como si yo dijera `instagram.com/pepe` es una pagina única, o lo que varia en cada pagina es solo lo que se imprime, es decir lo que viene de la base de datos.

Comment: No, imagina si tuvieran 4000 usuarios, ¿entonces 4000 archivos?

Comment: Se cargan dinámicamente los datos dentro de la misma página. Por eso todos tenemos el mismo formato siempre.

Comment: Exacto, un ejemplo claro seria el uso de plantillas o componentes donde puedes modificarlo a tu antojo